# Filter no longer works in report

Tags: civireport

We created a report to list the contacts without a contactsubtype.
Previously, it worked, since a recent update it no longer works.
The report is based on a filter "contacsubtype is not one of" followed by a list of all contactsubtypes in use.
What has changed?

Comment: What are the Civi versions where it does / does not work?

Comment: Now latest update 5.20. Previous about a year ago.

Comment: Which report template are you using?

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP Contact report with filter ... (as mentionned in the question)

Comment: Do you have any technical knowledge? If so you can see whether the query generated is correct on the Developer tab of the report. If you think this is a bug in civicrm. You can file an issue on lab.civicrm.org. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/issue-tracking/#guidelines for how to do this.